# Unable to call python code from dart language

Tags: python, parsing, server, dart, flutter

Hy !. Actually I am connecting to my my google cloud vm instance using python language by using following modules autobahn, twisted. My google cloud vm instance is working perfectly to be receiving and sending images back to python client file.

But, as we are developing our Android/IOS application on flutter, I need to call my python code from dart so that I can call my python function from flutter application. But I am unable to find any way how to do it.
Here is my client code, which will be connecting to server deployed at vm instance.

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, \
                                   WebSocketClientFactory
 import main
import jsonpickle
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
class MyClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):



def onConnect(self, response):
  print("Server connected: {0}".format(response.peer))

def onOpen(self):
  print("WebSocket connection open.")

  def hello():

     # opening the image file and encoding in base64
     path = "/home/abdullah/Desktop/Clocktower_Panorama_20080622_20mb.jpg"
     image = main.load_image(path)
     encoded = jsonpickle.encode(image)
     # printing the size of the encoded image which is sent
     # print("Encoded size of the sent image: {0} bytes".format(len(encoded_string)))

     # sending the encoded image
     self.sendMessage(encoded.encode('utf-8'))

  hello()


  def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
      print("Output processed image received")
      output = main.image_post_process(payload)
      plt.imshow(output)
      plt.show()
      print("Done")
      reactor.stop()

    # plt.show()
  def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
      print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))



  if __name__ == '__main__':
     time1 = time.time()

     import sys

     from twisted.python import log
     from twisted.internet import reactor

     # log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

     factory = WebSocketClientFactory()
     factory.protocol = MyClientProtocol

     reactor.connectTCP("34.73.158.146", 5903, factory)
     # reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 9933, factory)

     reactor.run()
    time2 = time.time()
     print("Total time is ", time2-time1)
```

please tell me how can I solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Without some of your sample code, we can't give you informed assistance.

Comment: Can't make sense of "I need to parse my python code to dart". What does that mean. Why don't you communicate using HTTP requests and JSON or similar from Flutter to your cloud server?

Comment: @JordanSinger I have added code

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, I changed it to " I need to call my python code from dart language ". Is it right now ?

Comment: There is no good way to call that from Flutter. Better to re-build that in Dart.

Comment: Do you have a way to call that from Android Java/Kotlin? (or ObjectC/Swift in case you want to target iOS)?

Comment: But, will flutter have packages like these, which can send connection requests ?

Comment: Let suppose, I write the client side with dart language and send and send requests from it. Should I have to convert server side code language to dart also ?

Comment: Your python code looks like simple websockets usage. Use the flutter websockets package.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dartpy lib to solve that problem by using that code inside of the dart code

this is an example

```
import 'package:dartpy/dartpy.dart';
import 'package:dartpy/dartpy_annotations.dart';
part 'gen_dartpy_example.g.dart';

@PyFunction(module: 'multiply')
int multiply(int a, int b) => pymultiply(a, b);

@PyFunction(module: 'multiply', name: 'multiply')
double mult_double(double a, double b) => pymultiplydouble(a, b);

@PyFunction(module: 'multiply', name: 'multiply')
num mult_num(num a, num b) => pymultiplynum(a, b);

void main() {
  try {
    print(multiply(6, 4));
    print(mult_double(6.13, 5.2));
    print(mult_num(6, 5.2));
    print(mult_num(6, 2));
  } on DartPyException catch (e) {
    if (pyErrOccurred()) {
      dartpyc.PyErr_Print();
    }
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

for more information, you can check this link about that lib:https://pub.dev/packages/dartpy